# Spring - Post Mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a way that when you have a code:

```java
@PostMapping("/test")
public boolean test(@RequestBody String data) {
    //code and stuff
}
```

You could send information in the post request url? for example

```
localhost:8080/test?username=username
```

Comment: It could be get mapping too

Comment: You would want to check out `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable`.

Comment: Please assign upvotes and mark the correct answer, so this question gets closed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `@RequestParam`:

```java
@PostMapping("/test")
public boolean test(@RequestParam String username, @RequestBody String data) {
    //code and stuff
}
```

In the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) we can read the following:

> Supported for annotated handler methods in Spring MVC and Spring
> WebFlux as follows:
>
> - In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form
>   data, and parts in multipart requests. This is because the Servlet API combines query parameters and form data into a single map called
>   "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body.
> - In Spring WebFlux, "request parameters" map to query parameters only.
>   To work with all 3, query, form data, and multipart data, you can use
>   data binding to a command object annotated with ModelAttribute.

Comment: Is your issue solved now? If it is and my answer helped you consider upvoting it and accepting it as the answer so that your question can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@RequestParam` annotation.

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public boolean test(@RequestBody String data, @RequestParam String username) {
    //code and stuff
}
```

If you need to call it something else you can also specify that

```
@RequestParam("username") String whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix request body and request params.

In your example, you can read the username request param this way:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public boolean test(@RequestBody String data, @RequestParam String username) {
    //code and stuff
}
```